# Is there any way to Save a Custom Plugin's Post ID into Post Meta Database and Display it to Any Wordpress or PHP page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using a plugin which generates a Post ID number for every woocommerce order and that is different from Woocommerce Order Number.
I want to save that post ID number into order Post Meta and display that on Different PHP pages like Woocommerce Email Notification Pages.

I tried to fetch that ID from Woocommerce Thankyou page through cookies and display them on Email Notification but ThankYou.php page runs at last of process and Email Notification pages work before thankyou page so that doesn't work.

```
 if ( ! function_exists( 'yith_wcevti_set_args_mail_template' ) ) {
 /**
 * Define the args to mail template
 * @param $post
 * @return array|mixed|void
 */
 function yith_wcevti_set_args_mail_template($post)
   {
    $args = array();

    $post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '', true);
```

This code is in my plugin's function page, I wanted to Save $post->ID from here to Post Meta and Display that to Any Wordpress or PHP page.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try kw update_post_meta or add_post_meta might help you

Comment: update_post_meta( $order_id, '_cookie_ticketidno', $post->ID; 

this doesn't work for me, can you provide me a proper code ?